# store database data into json file using python

Tags: python, django, json, django-views

In my app I am trying to save the database data into a JSON file.

Here is my views.py:

```
if request.POST:
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            form.save()

            JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
            json_serializer = JSONSerializer()
            with open("book.json", "w") as out:
                json_serializer.serialize(Book.objects.all(), stream=out)

        return redirect('/index/')
    return render_to_response('addbook.html',{ 'form':form },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am using serializer for doing that.
The problem is that the data is saved in the database, but not written to the file.

I am getting the following error,while running the above code

```
IOError at /addbook/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fixtures/book.json'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/addbook/
Django Version: 1.3.7
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fixtures/book.json'
Exception Location: /root/Samples/DemoApp/DemoApp/views.py in addbook, line 53
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
```

Comment: you must put the correct path for book.json

Comment: Well the code seems to run fine , Could it be a permission issue

Comment: Catherine,how to set path,as my .json file is in a folder named fixtures inside my app.Can you share me a small idea

Comment: you can use your settings.PROJECT_ROOT to locate your json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = "{0}/app_name/fixtures/book.json".format(settings.PROJECT_ROOT)
with open(path, "w") as out:
    json_serializer.serialize(Book.objects.all(), stream=out)
```